# How to CompareTo two Object without known about their real type

Tags: java, linked-list, compareto

I have to implement a one linked list but it should put object in appropriate position.
Everything was OK when I use it in conjunction with specific class, but when I tried make it universal and argument of method insert was Object some problem appeared.
When I want to input Object in right position I should use CompareTo method, but there isn't method in Object class!
The problem is how to compare two object elements without known about their real types.
Maybe I should use generic class type? But what about CompareTo? Or maybe combine with Element class and place CompareTo there?
I suppose it is feasible. :)

```
public void insert(Object o)
{
   Element el = new Element(o);
   //  initializing and setting iterators

   while(!it.isDone() && ((it.current().getValue())).CompareTo(o)<0) 
                         // it.current() returns Element of List
   {    
      //move interators
   }
//...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two options:

- make each object's class implement `java.lang.Comparable` and write the comparison logic for each class there, then just accept `Comparable` instead of `Object` and call `compareTo()`
- create a `comparator` property of your list and set it on construction. The concrete comparator (implementation of `java.util.Comparator`) should know how to compare the objects that are put in this particular instance of your list.

Comment: Good answer. I would recommend making it generic though by class LinkedList<T extends Comparable<T>> { public void insert(T t) { ... } public T get(...) { ... }.